# Laravel 5 - Error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::fire() after every composer update

Tags: php, laravel

After composer update, this error comes out.

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmpWh.jpg)

I solve the problem with this instruction

http://qaru.site/questions/17319093/laravel-5-error-call-to-undefined-method-illuminateeventsdispatcherfire/26245253#26245253

But I have to do it after every update.
How can I solve the problem once and for all?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dispatcher::dispatch($event)` instead of `Disaptcher::fire($event)`. The `fire()` method has been deprecated and removed a long time ago.

Comment: But I do not use the fire () method myself
When I do a code search, I don’t find a method call
For example, This code is causing an error
    public function accept($id)
    {
        $sender = User::find($id);

        if (!$sender) {
            return response(['error' => 'Sender is not exist'], 500);
        }

        Auth::user()->acceptFriendRequest($sender);
        Auth::user()->notifications()
            ->where('type', 'App\Notifications\FriendRequest')
            ->where('data->user_id', $id)
            ->delete();

        return ['success' => true];
    }

Comment: It's hard to tell what goes wrong without a proper stack trace of the error.

Comment: Auth::user()->befriend($recipient); - this error
http://joxi.ru/zANb3y9HvW3e6A

Comment: The `hootlex/laravel-friendships` package is outdated. See [`Friendable` trait](https://github.com/hootlex/laravel-friendships/blob/0100718545bad757006737c21a7b35dc5c52b443/src/Traits/Friendable.php#L35). It uses `Event::fire()` (the same as `Dispatcher::fire()`) which has been removed with Laravel 5.4 or so.

Comment: please tell me what to do?
Use another package?

Comment: Use another package; look for a maintained and updated fork; create your own maintained and updated fork; rebuild the package logic in your application; ask for help in the packages' GitHub issues; rollback to your previous Laravel version; ... I cannot make that decision for you. ;)

Comment: Which package I can use?

Comment: If I rewrite the code inside this package, it will not return when composer update?

Comment: Never change code inside the `vendor` directory. It will be overwritten when you use `composer install` or `composer update`. Also, it is dirty and not suitable for continuous integration, etc.

Comment: Help, how can I then correct this error and suffer the least loss?